# Using Resource Hacker on signed exe

Tags: resources, exe, sign

I want to translate a program with Resource Hacker. But, if I modify exe file with

Resource Hacker; it will lose its sign (SHA-1).

How to modify exe without losing the sign?

Answer (score 0):

Never.
A sign will guarantee the integrity of the file. When u r hacking something, u destroy the integrity of file.
The only way is just resign it.